# What is the difference between virtual function and pure virtual function in C++ in when both not defined in base class?

Tags: c++

This question is not duplicated because I add a condition "when both not defined in base class".
If in a base class C, I make a statement `virtual void display();` and it is never defined in classs C, it is a virtual function. Am I right? If I make a statement like "virtual void display()=0;" it is a pure virtual function.
So in both situation, derived class must define the display function. So why should we need pure virtual function? Or what is the problem in my statement?

Comment: You will end up with a linker error, that simple.

Comment: there is no difference between a pure virtual method and a method that has no definition in the base class. Thats just the definition of pure virtual (aka abstract). But you need to put the `=0;` if you want  to make the method abstract

Comment: @tobi303 So there is no need to use pure virtual function, Because when I need to use it, I can just use an un-pure virtual function which is not defined in the base function. Right?

Comment: @Jason no, wrong. There is no "un-pure virtual function that is not defined in the base class".

Comment: @tobi303 You mean un-pure virtual function must be defined in the base class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So in both situation, derived class must define the display function

Incorrect. Only pure virtual functions must be overridden by a derived class in order for that derived class to be concrete.

> So why should we need pure virtual function?

To specify that a type is [abstract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_type), which prevents it's instantiation.

> What is the difference between virtual function and pure virtual function in C++ in when both not defined in base class?

A pure virtual function is something that makes a class abstract, as I mentioned.

By declaring a function, you promise that there will be a definition for it. If there is no definition, then the program is ill formed. Pure virtual functions are exceptions in that it's not mandatory to define them (but you may). So in short, a non pure virtual without a definition is a bug.

Comment: un-pure virtual function also must be overriden. Because the base class doesn't define the virtual function which I already said.

Comment: @Jason No. The derived class will be concrete even without overriding the non defined virtual in the buggy parent.

Comment: For your new version answer, "a non pure virtual without a definition is a bug", you mean without a definition in the base class is a bug or in the derived class? If it is not defined in the bass class but defined in derived class, is it still a bug?

Comment: @Jason Yes, even if the derived class overrides the function, the base class is still buggy.

Comment: @Jason: It is a bug. The `= 0` you state for the pure virtual function is the statement "there may not be a definition for this function" that makes the absence of definition well-formed, guaranteeing a compiler error if you try to instantiate the base class. Declaring a function non-pure virtual, and not defining it, is ill-formed code. (Note that you *may* actually *define* a pure virtual function. You may still not instantiate the base class.)

Comment: @DevSolar Suppose I'll never instantiate the base class. I can declare some functions but not define them in the base class and define them in the derived class. If I don't call them in the base class, it won't produce bug. Right? But if it is a non-pure virtual function this doesn't work? If so, why?

Comment: @Jason: Not defining them **is** a bug. Calling them is merely **exposing** the bug.

Comment: @DevSolar I know what you mean. But sometimes, we just do it on purpose. For example, we don't want users to use = operator. We must declare it without define, so the compiler won't implement an = operator itself.

Comment: So this question is not about vortual vs. pure virtual at all, but about disabling `operator=` for a class?

Comment: The disabling thing is just in my logic to consider the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

"Pure virtual method" is just the name for a method, that has no definition in the class where it is declared. You must declare a pure virtual method as such to avoid linker errors. Consider this simple example:

```
/* abstract classes */
struct Broken { virtual void foo(); };
struct Fixed  { virtual void foo()=0; };

/* implementations */
struct A : Broken { void foo(){} };
struct B : Fixed  { void foo(){} };

int main() {
    //Broken* a = new A(); delete a; // (*)
    Fixed* a = new B(); delete a;
    return 0;
}
```

(*) creates a linker error (even if the object that is created has a `foo()` definition). To tell the compiler that the method is pure virtual you must put the `=0;`.

> [...]why must non-pure virtual function be defined in the base class?

Thats just how it is defined. There is something: Methods without definition in the base class. We give a name to it: pure virtual methods. It does not make sense to argue, why pure virtual have no definition in the base class or whether non-pure virtual methods are allowed to have no definition in the base class.

Comment: So I can say a non-pure virtual function must be defined in the base class. Right? If so, a non virtual function even can only be declared in the base class and not defined, why must non-pure virtual function be defined in the base class?

Comment: A pure virtual function is allowed to be defined, but it must still be overridden.   That defined function might, for example, be called by an overriding function in a derived class.

Comment: @tobi303 Actually, in my comment, I mean a normal function which has nothing to do with virtual can be declared and not defined in the base class and defined in the derived class.

Comment: usually anything that you declare you also must define somewhere. virtual methods are no exception, but pure virtual methods are.

Comment: Yeah, it is the usual case. But if you delete the virvual key word in Broken and A, it works. In some special case, we do it on purpose. For example, we don't want users to use = operator. We must declare it without define, so the compiler won't implement an = operator itself.

Comment: @Jason please look at the example again. I am not using `foo` but nevertheless without declaring it as pure virtual it is not even possible to create an instance of a subclass. As it is `Broken` is really completely broken.

Comment: @Jason ...and I also cannot fix it by removing `virtual`, because then there is no polymorphism (which is the reason why I put `virtual` in the first place)